# try/catch expected '(' error

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm trying to use try/catch. I'm pretty much sure that the syntax is right but not sure why I'm getting this error: '(' expected catch^

Here's my code:

```
    Random first_number = new Random();
    Random second_number = new Random();

    int number_1;
    int number_2;

    int answer_M;
    String answer;
    int correctAnswer_M = 0;


    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        try
        {
            number_1 = first_number.nextInt(10);
            number_2 = second_number.nextInt(10);

            System.out.print("\n         " + i + ".) ");
            System.out.print(number_1 + " multiplied by " + number_2 +" = ");
            answer_M = Integer.parseInt(answer);

                if(answer_M==(number_1 * number_2))
                {
                    correctAnswer_M = correctAnswer_M + 1;
                }
        }
        catch
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter an answer.");
            i=i-1;
        }
    }
```

Looking forward to your response. Thanks! :)

Comment: **What** are you catching?

Comment: I want the system to print an error message telling the user to enter an answer. @ssantos' answer below worked on my query... Thanks a lot guys! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about a missing `(` just after `catch`. You need to add the `Exception` you're catching.-

```
catch (Exception e)
```

More about catch blocks [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: Note that a given exception here will also catch all its subclasses

Comment: Glad it helped :) Btw, welcome to stackoverflow. If any answer was useful, please, consider upvoting/accepting as it may be useful for other users too.

Answer (score 3):

You have to catch a specific type of exception.

```
try {
    // Some exception throwing code here.
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler what kind of exception you expect to catch. The most general one would be to catch a `Throwable`. e.g:

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Have a look at the [official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) for more information.

Comment: You shouldnt catch an 
    Error

Comment: @Ezequiel You should be as specific as possible, but that's not within the scope of the question.

Comment: Exception extends Throwable, but Error too. Programmers shouldnt catch Error in most of cases, Think about catching OutOfMemoryError or StrackOverFLowError in a piece of bussines code. Regards.